# Convert a for loop with conditions from c to python

Tags: python, c, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Variables:

```
n = 378282246310005
m = n
i = 1
sum1 = 0
sum2 = 0
sum11 = 0
```

I want to convert the following c-code to python-code:

```
for (m = n, i = 1; m != 0; m = m / 10, i++)
    {
        r = m % 10;
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            sum1 += r;
        }
        else
        {
            sum2 += r * 2;
        }
        while (sum2 > 0)
        {
            z = sum2 % 10;
            sum11 = sum11 + z;
            sum2 = sum2 / 10;
        }
    }
```

I came up with the following code for python, but it does not work:

```
for m in range(m!=0):

    r = m % 10

    if (i % 2 != 0):
        sum1 += r

    else:
        sum2 += r * 2

    while sum2 > 0:
        z = sum2 % 10
        sum11 = sum11 + z
        sum2 = sum2 / 10

    m = m / 10
    i = i + 1
```

Where do I have to change the logic or the code, for it to work?

Comment: `m in range(m!=0):` is not `(...; m != 0;...)`?

Comment: Replace your `for m in range(m!=0)` with `m = n  i = 1  while (m != 0):` (three lines of code)

Comment: `sum2 / 10` will produce a floating point result in Python 3.  If you want integer division, use `sum2 // 10`.

Answer (score 0):

Variables Initialization:

```
n = 378282246310005
m = n
i = 1
sum1 = 0
sum2 = 0
sum11 = 0
```

You could use a while loop:

```
while(m!=0):
        r = m % 10
        if (i % 2) != 0 :
            sum1 += r
        else:
            sum2 += r * 2
        while (sum2 > 0):
            z = sum2 % 10
            sum11 = sum11 + z
            sum2 = sum2 // 10
        m = m // 10
        i+=1
```

EDIT1: Yes you are right, range(m!=0) is correct. I didn't know it was, you just taught me a new thing thank you!

And I added the double dash (m = m // 10)

Comment: if m is an integer , you might want to use // instead of / otherwise the termination condition might never be reached

Comment: `m in range(m!=0)` is perfectly valid but will not do what OP wants

Comment: none of the parenthesis characters in your code are needed, nor are they considered good style